# SQL queries returning different results when extending date range

Tags: sql

I have two tables, which for the sake of simplicity call Table1 and Table2.They both have two columns: ID and date. I want to filter out every row in Table1 where the ID is found in Table2 under an earlier date.

For example:

Table1:

```
ID   Date
X    20170105
Y    20170304
```

Table2:

```
ID   Date
X    20161230
Y    20170306
```

The desired output would be ID Y with date 20170304 since ID X occurs in Table2 in a previous date.

I ran this code twice, once for the whole year then separated it by the months and once only for the month of April. For some reason, I am getting different results.

Code for the whole year:

```
proc sql; 
Create table whole_year as 
Select distinct a.ID, a.date 
From table1 a 
Left join table2 b 
On a.ID = b.ID and a.date > b.date 
Where b.ID is null
And a.date >= 20170101; 
Quit;
```

The code for just April is exactly the same except

```
a.date between 20170401 and 20170430
```

Comment: Surprise, surprise! You change your query and it returns different results. /sarcasm_off … In the sample data you've provided, 1st query returns 1 row, and 2nd 0 rows ***because there are NO April dates***. _I assume you're actually referring to differences in data you haven't bothered to show._ How do you expect people to help you when you don't even bother to show what unexpected results you get! (I could hazard a guess seeing at BETWEEN that you might not understand that dangers of that particular feature in how it can produce incorrect results.)

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the date condition from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause of the join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.ID, a.date 
FROM table1 a 
LEFT JOIN table2 b 
    ON a.ID = b.ID AND
       a.date > b.date AND
       a.date BETWEEN 20170401 AND 20170430
WHERE b.ID is null;
```